# How to edit a specific element of a Set in Java, where the element is a List object?

Tags: java, set

I had some code in Java using an ArrayList of an Array List but caller needs a Set<List> back so I've converted most of my code to use Set.  mDetails is now definition like this:

```
Set<List<String>> mDetails = new HashSet<List<String>>();
```

I have this function that needs to be converted to use the Set<List> type.

```
public void addField( int row, String value ) {
    this.mDetails.get(row).add( value );
}
```

Another function finds the correct row to modify and this function adds the given value as a new column.  If there is a more direct way I'd be willing to remove this function.  I also tried:

```
this.mDetails[row].add( value );
```

Sorry to ask this question but the internet assumes your asking about JDBC Result Sets when asking this question.

Comment: There is really no such concept as a 'specific row' of a `Set`, as in, addressable by index. That collection is by default unordered, but there are versions that do have some ordering. Your best best might be `LinkedHashSet` with iteration. This situation is somewhat changed in Java 21

Comment: A `Set` is unordered by definition. So your `get(row)` and `[row]` makes no sense. Are those really supposed to be an index into the list, or an ordinal within the list?

Comment: @g00se The addField function above is the original function when it worked on an ArrayList of an ArrayList.  Maybe let's ask the question in another way.  The task needs to find a specific item and append a value.  So let's say the list contains [["s"], ["m"], ["l"]].  I want to find the medium or m item in the set and add "111" to it so I end up with [["s"], ["m", "111"], ["l"]]

Comment: OK, so what criteria would you have for finding that item (that `List`) - part of it or all of it, or what?

Comment: What do you expect the signature of `addField` to look like after the change?

Comment: @tgdavies If it handles the entire operation then public void addField( String updateStr, String appendStr ) .

Comment: @BasilBourque then maybe the type of set should change?

Comment: @g00se The first field in each row (the List) has the size in it.

Comment: It sounds as though you want a `Map<String,List<String>>` and not a `Set` at all.

Comment: You should define your terms "field" and "row". Your Question is not entirely clear. Collections in Java contain *elements*. See [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) by Oracle.

Comment: As @BasilBourque says, iterate and create a new `Set`

Answer (score 3):

### No can do

A [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) tracks each element in the set by its [hash code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). This means it is crucial that your elements placed in that set never produce a different hash code.

Your elements in your `HashSet` object are each a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) object. How does a `List` implementation produce its hash code? By overriding [`Object#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), as documented [its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#hashCode()). That documentation explains that the hash code of the list is calculated from a hash code of each of its elements. This means  **a `List` in a `HashSet` must never be mutated** (adding, deleting, replacing, or altering its elements).

Your goal of mutating the `List` elements within your `HashSet` violates this rule, this requirement for a stable unchanging hash code.

So your Question is technically nonsensical. A `List` in a `HashSet` must not be altered.

### Workaround: Replace each list

The workaround is to withdraw the `List` from the `HashSet`, alter the `List`, and add the changed `List` object back to the `HashSet` where it gets tracked by its new hash code value.

But you do not define how you want to identify any particular element of your `HashSet`, any particular `List` element. You seem to indicate an index or ordinal number in your mind. But a `Set` by definition, and a `HashSet` in particular, has no order. So there the elements are not numbered. A `Set` has no index or ordinal number for its elements. So I cannot write any example code.

---

Perhaps you should post another Question where you describe the problem you are trying to solve with this set-of-lists. I suspect a different approach might better serve you.

Comment: I've been reading up on other set types.  I suppose the suggestion should have been to change the set type.  Also I've have now read other documentation that says if the HashSet has been modified it will throw an exception...  So right now I'm just trying to get this to work and meet the criteria of the caller.

Comment: @Keith On Stack Overflow, you ask a specific question to get a specific answer. For open-ended discussions, use a forums site such as CodeRanch.com.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer that I came up with... and simplest was to  keep my code as a List<List> then to convert it to a HashSet during the return.

```
return new HashSet<List<String>>( rbList.mDetails );
```

This allows me to use all the standard operations on the list and I didn't have to change any code. Hope this helps.